# Is this DLL required any longer for Application Insights? Microsoft.ai.agent.intercept.dll

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have been up until now using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights DLL v2.20.

My web.config file has specified this:

```
<httpModules>
        <add xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
</httpModules>
```

This appears to pull down the Microsoft.AI.Agent.Intercept.dll file.

However, I've since upgraded to v2.21 of ApplicationInsights and the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net) doesn't reference this web.config segment to include it.

Therefore, do I take from this that I no longer need to include a reference to the Microsoft.AI.Agent.Intercept.dll? Even if I do need this, do I still need to include an explicit reference in my .csproj file?

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept">
  <Version>$(ApplicationInsightsAgentIntercept)</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does it work without the reference?

Comment: Hard to tell if the Application Insights is working exactly as before, but I see no indication to suggest it's not.

Comment: What is the framework of your Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see the  `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept.dll` is compatible with `.NET 4.0 and 4.5` framework versions.

[image]

- But, it allowed me to install in `.NET 4.7.2` and later versions.
- When you add Application Insights from the `Connected Services`, by default all the `dll's` which are required to log the basic traces are added.

[image]

- If you want to trace /log any additional requests/logs, then you can add the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept.dll`.
- AFAIK, no need to include the intercept dll and if you want only the default traces from the application you can remove the explicit references from the `.csproj` file.
- The latest Application Insights SDK will take care of the telemetry.